# Is there any formal difference at all between PostgreSQL functions with OUT parameters and with TABLE results?

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, user-defined-functions, out-parameters

Consider these two PostgreSQL functions:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_1 (v1 INTEGER, v2 OUT INTEGER)
AS $$
BEGIN
    v2 := v1;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_2 (v1 INTEGER)
RETURNS TABLE(v2 INTEGER)
AS $$
BEGIN
    v2 := v1;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

In any "ordinary" procedural SQL language (e.g. Transact-SQL), the two types of functions would be quite different. `f_1` would actually be a procedure, whereas `f_2` would be a table-valued function. In SQL Server, the latter is returned from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES` like so:

```sql
SELECT r.routine_schema, r.routine_name
FROM   information_schema.routines r
WHERE  r.routine_type = 'FUNCTION'
AND    r.data_type = 'TABLE'
```

In PostgreSQL, this doesn't work, however. The following query shows that there is essentially no difference between the signatures of `f_1` and `f_2`:

```sql
SELECT r.routine_name, r.data_type, p.parameter_name, p.data_type
FROM   information_schema.routines r
JOIN   information_schema.parameters p
USING (specific_catalog, specific_schema, specific_name);
```

The above yields:

```
routine_name | data_type | parameter_name | data_type
-------------+-----------+----------------+----------
f_1          | integer   | v1             | integer
f_1          | integer   | v2             | integer
f_2          | integer   | v1             | integer
f_2          | integer   | v2             | integer
```

Things don't get much better when I have multiple columns returned from the functions, in case of which I don't even have a "formal" return type anymore. Just `record`:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_3 (v1 INTEGER, v2 OUT INTEGER, v3 OUT INTEGER)
AS $$
BEGIN
    v2 := v1;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_4 (v1 INTEGER)
RETURNS TABLE(v2 INTEGER, v3 INTEGER)
AS $$
BEGIN
    v2 := v1;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

... I'll get:

```
routine_name | data_type | parameter_name | data_type
-------------+-----------+----------------+----------
f_3          | record    | v1             | integer
f_3          | record    | v2             | integer
f_3          | record    | v3             | integer
f_4          | record    | v1             | integer
f_4          | record    | v2             | integer
f_4          | record    | v3             | integer
```

If coming from other databases, clearly the *intent* of the lexical signature is quite different. As an Oracle person, I expect `PROCEDURES` to have side-effects, whereas `FUNCTIONS` don't have any side-effects (unless in an autonomous transaction) and can be safely embedded in SQL. I know that PostgreSQL cleverly treats all functions as tables, but I don't think it's a good idea to design `OUT` parameters as table columns in any query...

#### My question is:

Is there any formal difference at all between the two ways to declare functions? If there is, how can I discover it from the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` or from the `PG_CATALOG`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\df public.f_*` does this

```
select
    n.nspname as "Schema",
    p.proname as "Name",
    pg_catalog.pg_get_function_result(p.oid) as "Result data type",
    pg_catalog.pg_get_function_arguments(p.oid) as "Argument data types",
    case
        when p.proisagg then 'agg'
        when p.proiswindow then 'window'
        when p.prorettype = 'pg_catalog.trigger'::pg_catalog.regtype then 'trigger'
        else 'normal'
    end as "Type"
from
    pg_catalog.pg_proc p
    left join
    pg_catalog.pg_namespace n on n.oid = p.pronamespace
where
    p.proname ~ '^(f_.*)$'
    and n.nspname ~ '^(public)$'
order by 1, 2, 4;
```

which returns this

```
                                          List of functions
 Schema | Name |       Result data type        |            Argument data types             |  Type  
--------+------+-------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+--------
 public | f_1  | integer                       | v1 integer, OUT v2 integer                 | normal
 public | f_2  | TABLE(v2 integer)             | v1 integer                                 | normal
 public | f_3  | record                        | v1 integer, OUT v2 integer, OUT v3 integer | normal
 public | f_4  | TABLE(v2 integer, v3 integer) | v1 integer                                 | normal
(4 rows)
```

To drop a function it is necessary to pass its *input* (`IN` and `INOUT`) arguments data types. Then I guess the function name and its *input* arguments data types do form its signature. And to change the returned data type it is necessary to first drop it and recreate.

Comment: Very nice. I suspect his goes in the same direction as [what I've discovered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24513067/521799) about the `pg_proc.proretset` column. If psql formally runs this type of query, my question can be answered positively. The two function specifications are not the same.

Comment: @Lukas Edit about function signature

Comment: `OUT` parameters are not part of the function signature. You don not need them to drop a function.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto: Do you happen to know how `pg_get_function_result` is implemented?

Comment: To be precise: `IN` and `INOUT` arguments. I added a bit to my answer.

Comment: @LukasEder: [Details for `pg_get_function_result(func_oid)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG-TABLE)

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: That explains *what* it does, but I'm really interested in a query that can help me formally reverse-engineer the table type. Ideally, I'd have output more or less compatible to `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`, like SQL Server (I'm doing this to generate Java code with [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org)). It's starting to get a bit out-of-scope for this particular Stack Overflow question, I know

Comment: @Lukas `pg_get_function_result` is internal. Only browsing the source will reveal it.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto: Yep. That's what I feared :)

Answer (score 2):

It *appears* that the `pg_catalog.pg_proc.proretset` flag contains a *hint* about whether the function returns a set (i.e. a table):

```sql
SELECT   r.routine_name, r.data_type, p.parameter_name, 
         p.data_type, pg_p.proretset
FROM     information_schema.routines r
JOIN     information_schema.parameters p
USING   (specific_catalog, specific_schema, specific_name)
JOIN     pg_namespace pg_n
ON       r.specific_schema = pg_n.nspname
JOIN     pg_proc pg_p
ON       pg_p.pronamespace = pg_n.oid
AND      pg_p.proname = r.routine_name
WHERE    r.routine_schema = 'public'
AND      r.routine_name IN ('f_1', 'f_2', 'f_3', 'f_4')
ORDER BY routine_name, parameter_name;
```

The above would yield:

```
routine_name | data_type | parameter_name | data_type | proretset
-------------+-----------+----------------+-----------+----------
f_1          | record    | v1             | integer   | f
f_1          | record    | v2             | integer   | f
f_2          | record    | v1             | integer   | t
f_2          | record    | v2             | integer   | t
f_3          | record    | v1             | integer   | f
f_3          | record    | v2             | integer   | f
f_3          | record    | v3             | integer   | f
f_4          | record    | v1             | integer   | t
f_4          | record    | v2             | integer   | t
f_4          | record    | v3             | integer   | t
```

#### INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS emulation

For what it's worth and in case someone needs this crazy thing, here's the beautiful query I came up with to emulate SQL Server's nice `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` implementation that returns table-valued function columns (which is what we really needed when supporting table-valued functions in [jOOQ's code generator](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3375)):

```sql
SELECT 
  p.proname AS TABLE_NAME,
  columns.proargname AS COLUMN_NAME, 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY p.oid ORDER BY o.ordinal) AS ORDINAL_POSITION,
  format_type(t.oid, t.typtypmod) AS DATA_TYPE,
  information_schema._pg_char_max_length(t.oid, t.typtypmod) AS CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH,
  information_schema._pg_numeric_precision(t.oid, t.typtypmod) AS NUMERIC_PRECISION,
  information_schema._pg_numeric_scale(t.oid,t.typtypmod) AS NUMERIC_SCALE,
  not(t.typnotnull) AS IS_NULLABLE
FROM pg_proc p,
LATERAL generate_series(1, array_length(p.proargmodes, 1)) o(ordinal),
LATERAL (
  SELECT 
    p.proargnames[o.ordinal], 
    p.proargmodes[o.ordinal], 
    p.proallargtypes[o.ordinal]
) columns(proargname, proargmode, proargtype),
LATERAL (
  SELECT pg_type.oid oid, pg_type.* 
  FROM pg_type 
  WHERE pg_type.oid = columns.proargtype
) t
WHERE p.proretset
AND proargmode = 't'
AND p.proname LIKE 'f%';
```

The above nicely returns (column names shortened for SO):

```
table_name | column_name  | ordinal | data_type | length | precision | scale | nullable
f_2        | v2           |       1 | integer   |        |        32 |     0 | t
f_4        | v2           |       1 | integer   |        |        32 |     0 | t
f_4        | v3           |       2 | integer   |        |        32 |     0 | t
```

Answer (score 2):

`RETURNS TABLE()` is effectively the same as `OUT` parameters combined with `RETURNS SETOF ...`
Without the additional `SETOF` keyword, a function with `OUT` parameters always returns a **single row**, while a function with `RETURNS TABLE()` can return **0-n rows**.

Your example just happens not to exhibit the difference, due to how it's written.

This is reflected in the flag `proretset` of the system catalog `pg_proc`. [The manual:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/catalog-pg-proc.html)

> Function returns a set (i.e., multiple values of the specified data type)

The information schema view `information_schema.routines` is not particularly helpful in this regard. That's a watered-down standardized compromise to present information in a platform-independent form, hardly fit to portray the specifics in Postgres.

#### Function signature

[The manual:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createfunction.html#SQL-CREATEFUNCTION-OVERLOADING)

> Two functions are considered the same if they have the same names and
> **input** argument types, ignoring any `OUT` parameters

Where "input" argument types inlcude `IN` and `INOUT` parameters.

These two functions are instrumental when fiddling with function definitions. [The manual:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG-TABLE)

```
pg_get_function_arguments(func_oid) ... get argument list of function's definition (with default values)
pg_get_function_identity_arguments(func_oid) ... get argument list to identify a function (without default values)
```

More in these related answers:

- [How to get function parameter lists (so I can drop a function)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12127274/how-to-get-function-parameter-lists-so-i-can-drop-a-function-in-postgresql/12127714#12127714)
- [DROP FUNCTION without knowing the number/type of parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7622908/drop-function-without-knowing-the-number-type-of-parameters/7623246#7623246)

Comment: OK, fixed the mistake about `SETOF`. About the information schema: I am not saying anything is wrong with it. It's just not "first-hand" infiormation. It's a standardized compromise that does not reflect all Postgres-specific features.

Comment: Ah, very nice! `SETOF` is another great feature to return a row type from a concrete table. That's going to be quite useful as well... Good thing you undeleted your answer.

Comment: It would be really interesting to see what those `pg_get_function_xxx` functions really do, internally. Unnesting those `pg_proc.proargxxx` columns into a meaningful SQL statement doesn't seem so straightforward...

Comment: @LukasEder: I added links to answers that produce meaningful SQL statements.

Comment: I've updated my own answer with what I've meant. I was really looking for a means to emulate SQL Server's understanding of `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` with respect to table-valued functions. Maybe, this will eventually make it into PostgreSQL's `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` as well...?