# Parameter defaults for ALTER FUNCTION?

Tags: postgresql, function, plpgsql

I'm trying to migrate one of my oracle databases to Postgres 9.5. I`m currently trying to create the next function:

```
-- Generated by Ora2Pg, the Oracle database Schema converter, version 18.1
-- Copyright 2000-2017 Gilles DAROLD. All rights reserved.
-- DATASOURCE: dbi:Oracle:oralab

SET client_encoding TO 'UTF8';
SET search_path = repdev,public,oracle,utl_file,extensions;
show search_path;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Bl_Create_Flat_File_Pg.set_charset (file_id 
utl_file.file_type, p_title text DEFAULT NULL) RETURNS VOID AS $body$
BEGIN
.....
End;
--
$body$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
SECURITY DEFINER
STABLE;
ALTER FUNCTION Bl_Create_Flat_File_Pg.set_charset (file_id 
utl_file.file_type, p_title text DEFAULT NOT NULL ) OWNER TO repdev;
```

but when I`m running it in psql iget the next error:

> ```
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "DEFAULT"
> LINE 1: ...charset (file_id utl_file.file_type, p_title text DEFAULT NU...
> ```

Comment: if you don't specify default for the last argument it will be default null - just remove ` DEFAULT NULL` - it is so already in your case

Comment: There is no obvious syntax error in the provided statement: [test](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=91800e0859cc8110c5f2d2169e90ced0). Is it just single statement, or it is a part of some bigger script?

Comment: That is not true - without `DEFAULT NULL` you *have* to supply an argument, with it you don't have to. The error is surprising (I would have expected `schema "utl_file" does not exist`). Is this a modified or forked PostgreSQL you are running?

Comment: what do you mean by modified or forked ? just downloaded the offical postgresql 9.5 and installed it from souce files..

Comment: Hi, its part of an .sql dump file that I try to import to the db. I didnt include the body but the body includes some UTL_FILES.PUT_LINE and nothing more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the `ALTER FUNCTION` you only need to repeat the parameter definitions (actually only the parameter *types* are required), **not** the `default` clause of a parameter:

```
ALTER FUNCTION Bl_Create_Flat_File_Pg.set_charset(file_id utl_file.file_type, p_title text) 
OWNER TO repdev;
```

or shorter:

```
ALTER FUNCTION Bl_Create_Flat_File_Pg.set_charset(utl_file.file_type, text) 
OWNER TO repdev;
```

---

If you compare the documentation of the [CREATE FUNCTION](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html) statement, which is:

```
CREATE [ OR REPLACE ] FUNCTION
name ( [ [ argmode ] [ argname ] argtype [ { DEFAULT | = } default_expr ] [, ...] ] )
```

to the [ALTER FUNCTION](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterfunction.html) documentation:

```
ALTER FUNCTION name ( [ [ argmode ] [ argname ] argtype [, ...] ] )
```

you will notice that `ALTER FUNCTION` does not allow the `DEFAULT` clause.

If the code you have shown us really was generated by Ora2Pg then you should report that as an error to the Ora2Pg authors.

Comment: Thanks ! yes, it was generated by Ora2PG. I will report this bug.

Comment: @Mariel: The key word here is "function signature" and there are utility functions which the Ora2P guys *should* be using, particularly: `pg_get_function_identity_arguments(func_oid)` More: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12127714/939860