# How to pass the function argument value as a value to another function in PLpgSQL?

Tags: postgresql, function, plpgsql

I have the following function:

```
func_example(arg_1 anyelement, arg_2 anyelement);
```

Also, I

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_name(
        p_value_1    anyelement,
        ...
        p_value_n    anyelement,
        p_name_1     anyelement,
        ...
        p_name_n     anyelement)
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $func_name$
    DECLARE
        n    smallint,
    BEGIN
        n =: (see calculation of the number][1])

        FOR i IN (1..n) LOOP
            IF func_example(format('p_value_%s', i), format('p_name_%s', i)) THEN  -- a) fails  OR   
            IF func_example($i, $(i+n)) THEN  -- b) fails, too
                do_something;
            END IF;
        END LOOP;
    END;
AS $func_name$;
```

[1] https://stackoverflow.com/a/49408494/8895614

In case:

a) `p_value_1` is passed as `text` type,

b) a `syntax error at or near $`i arises.

Any workaround?

Tia

PS: I need to add more details in order to post the question because my post is mostly code!

Comment: why dont you use named arguments?..

Comment: `p_value_n` is a name argument, too; if I understand correct your remark. `p_value_n` is usually `smallint` or `DEFAULT` or `NULL` or `text` and `p_name_n` is usually `text`.

Comment: I call it by `SELECT func_name('1'::text, .., 'n'::text, 'name_1',..., NULL)` Within, the other function should be called by `func_example('1', 'name_1')`, ..., `func_example('n', 'name_n')`.

Comment: There is too little code and too many syntax errors in what you write. Can you come up with a *small* test case that you can post entirely and that exhibits the problem?

Comment: Please forget the syntax errors and concentrate only on the two if lines; `IF func_example(format('p_value_%s', i), format('p_name_%s', i)) THEN` and `IF func_example($i, $(i+n)) THEN` which both fail. Why?

Answer (score 1):

PLpgSQL is very static (and classical) language. There is not possible iterate over functions arguments. It is old-school language designed for static business processes. It is possible in C extensions. Probably it is possible other PL languages like PLPerl or PLPythonu.

Another solution is using a array as argument instead params. You can use a variadic functions too:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fx(a int, b variadic anyarray)
RETURNS void AS $$
BEGIN
  RAISE NOTICE '%', b[1:a];
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

```
postgres=# SELECT fx(1, 10, 20);
NOTICE:  {10}
┌────┐
│ fx │
╞════╡
│    │
└────┘
(1 row)

postgres=# SELECT fx(2, 10, 20);
NOTICE:  {10,20}
┌────┐
│ fx │
╞════╡
│    │
└────┘
(1 row)
```

Nothing more is possible in PLpgSQL. There is not possible to read parameter via `$n` where n is not numeric constant.