# Phantom Postgres table exists but can't be dropped?

Tags: postgresql

I seem to have some sort of phantom table in Postgres.

Suppose I do the following:

```
select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'public';
```

I get:

```
table_name     | table_type | ...
phantom_table    BASE TABLE
...
```

So, I run:

```
drop table phantom_table cascade;
```

And I get:

```
ERROR: table "phantom_table" does not exist
```

Things I've tried:

1. Checking for spelling errors and making sure the schema is correct (I've even copied/pasted table name out of information schema query results).
2. `vacuum`
3. Reconnecting.
4. Killing other running processes from my user (nobody else is using the DB).
5. Checking for active locks on the table (there aren't any).

Anybody have any other ideas for things I should try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have some white space at the end of the name.

The easiest way is to let the `format()` function generate you the correct table name and statement:

```
select format('drop table %I.%I;', table_schema, table_name) as drop_statement
from information_schema.tables 
where table_schema = 'public'
  and table_name like '%phantom%';
```

**Edit**: it seems that `psql` on Windows isn't able to handle an identifier with a new line in a `drop` statement (it does when creating the table however).

To workaround that, you can use a DO block:

```
do
$$
declare
 l_stmt text;
begin
  select format('drop table %I.%I;', table_schema, table_name) as drop_statement
    into l_stmt
  from information_schema.tables 
  where table_schema = 'public'
    and table_name like '%phantom%';
  execute l_stmt;    
end;
$$
;
```

Note this code assumes that only a single table with that name exists.

Comment: Interesting... the drop statement I get back does have a linebreak in the table name, but the statement still doesn't run.

Comment: @JohnChrysostom: then you have indeed some white space in the name. But the generated statement should be able to cope with that.

Comment: Couldn't get the generated statement to work - I suspect I'm fighting Windows/Unix line break differences. Was able to get it done using a modified version of this function, though... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202135/how-to-drop-multiple-tables-in-postgresql-using-a-wildcard Thanks for the help.